# The "Chok" Status of Kohanim Drinking Before the Service

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, intoxication, parashat-shemini

While reading the Parsha this past week, I was struck but what I thought was an interesting wording in the Passuk:

> ט  יַיִן וְשֵׁכָר אַל-תֵּשְׁתְּ אַתָּה וּבָנֶיךָ אִתָּךְ, בְּבֹאֲכֶם אֶל-אֹהֶל מוֹעֵד--וְלֹא תָמֻתוּ:  **חֻקַּת** עוֹלָם, לְדֹרֹתֵיכֶם.
>
> 9 'Drink no wine nor strong drink, thou, nor thy sons with thee, when ye go into the tent of meeting, that ye die not; it shall be a statute forever throughout your generations.

When describing the type of commandment this is, the Torah calls it "חֻקַּת". I've always been under the impression that the classification of "Chok" is used for commandments that are beyond human comprehension. The prohibition against doing the service intoxicated doesn't seem like it would fall under that category.

The above assumption is based on what is the quintessential Chok: The Parah Adumah. In Bamidbar 19:2, the Torah describes the Parah Adumah with the same phrase: "זֹאת חֻקַּת הַתּוֹרָה", and Rashi there writes:

> כתב בה חקה, גזירה היא מלפני ואין לך רשות להרהר אחריה
>
> Therefore, the Torah uses the term “statute.” I have decreed it; You have no right to challenge it

Rashi clearly says the term "Chok" (at least by Parah Adumah) is a classification of Mitzvos beyond human comprehension. However, I don't know offhand of any other examples (besides this question) where the term "Chok" is used, and whether it refers to a Mitzvah beyond human comprehension or not.

Does anyone know if any of the commentators comment on this?

As an aside, I looked into the Sefer Hachinuch to see if maybe it gave a reason, and it said that the reason for this prohibition is "Pashut", which adds to the question of why the wording of חֻקַּת is used (unless I'm simply misunderstanding the word חֻקַּת).

Comment: Have you looked at other places the word Chukkat is used in the Torah? Does it match your preconception? What examples show that? Have you considered that your expected connotation might only be true in usage of rabbinic hebrew?

Comment: Consider the fact that pagan rituals often **required** that the priests drink and lose control of themselves in order to "serve" their idols. Another possibility is that this says absolutely no drink and not just refrain from getting drunk.

Comment: May be that chok reffers to a periodic, perhaps quotidian habit or law (I am ont 100% sure)

Comment: May be that chok reffers to a periodic, repetitive, perhaps quotidian habit or law (I am ont 100% sure) חוקי הנשים in Esther,  שָׁוְא וּדְבַר-כָּזָב, הַרְחֵק מִמֶּנִּי--    רֵאשׁ וָעֹשֶׁר, אַל-תִּתֶּן-לִי;
הַטְרִיפֵנִי,    לֶחֶם חֻקִּי
mishley 30, 8. 
see shorashim radak חקק on the verse YOV 23, 4, quotidian

Comment: @DoubleAA Added example of Parah Adumah as per your comment.

Comment: @sabbahillel re: first point: Maybe, although based on the Sefer Hachinuch it would seem like this is an obvious Mitzvah. re: second point: I find it hard to accept that the Torah quantifying a Mitzvah would bring it to the category of "Chok". The Torah had to set up lines in order to for there to be set rules. I don't think monetary laws are Chukim because the Torah set up Shaveh Prutah, etc.

Comment: @sabbahillel You're in good company though. I was speaking with someone over Shabbos about this question, and he gave your second point as an answer as well ;)

Comment: @Salmononius2 Did you search Tanakh and that's all you found, or are you just quoting the one famous example that you've heard of. A quick search for me yields Exodus 12:14,17,22 ; 27:21 ; 28:43 ; 29:8 and then I gave up copying results to this comment. I think you need to do better than quoting the most famous example of one meaning and extrapolating to all usages. (Numbers 27:11 is particularly telling that your general rule isn't that much of a rule.)

Comment: By the way, check out [the _Sefer Hachinuch_'s entry on _para aduma_](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A_(%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%94)/%D7%A9%D7%A6%D7%96). Many people explain the reason for that _mitzva_. Not all of them do so after describing how hard it was for others to figure out.